# Update Textbox value when changes are made

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I use the code below to count cells that are blank and have a certain color.
I then store the count in a  textbox. The code works fine but i have to run the code for the textbox value to update. I need the textbox value to update when changes are made.

Tx in advance!

```
Sub CountBlankColors4()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim ColorCount(100) As Long

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select

    For Each c In Selection
        With c.Interior
            If .Pattern = xlSolid Then
                If .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893 Then
                    If IsEmpty(c) Then
                        ColorCount(.ColorIndex) = _
                          ColorCount(.ColorIndex) + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next c

    For J = 0 To 100
        If ColorCount(J) > 0 Then
            sTemp = ColorCount(J)
        End If
    Next J

    TextBox1.Value = sTemp
End Sub
```

Comment: Check out for the `Worksheet_Change()` event, there are lots of questions refering this topic in this site. That's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your first go might be to look into the `Worksheet_Change()` event there might be another way to deal with this. You could create an UDF (User Defined Function) that can be called like a normal function in your workbook. For example the below would count the cells in a range and will update when something in that range changes.

```
Public Function CountCells(RNG As Range) As Double

For Each CL In RNG
    If IsEmpty(CL) = True Then
        With CL.Interior
            If .Pattern = xlSolid And .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893 Then
                CountCells = CountCells + 1
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next CL

End Function
```

[image]

You could link the value of `C1` to a textbox.

Comment: Awesome! that is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: You are welcome @Joris, if this has answered your question please consider marking your question as answered.